# Relation of resistance between two metals and capacity

Tags: electromagnetism

My schoolbook goves the resistance between two metals in a material with conductivity $\sigma$ as $R=\frac{\epsilon_0}{\sigma C}$, but they don't show how they got this result. Can someone show me how to derive this formula?

Answer (score 1):

The conductivity of a material of length $l$, cross section $A$ and resistance $R$ is found by $\sigma = \frac{l}{R A}$. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_resistivity_and_conductivity).

The capacitance $C$ of two parallel plates is $C = \frac{\epsilon_0 A}{l}$. You can find it on [this page](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/pplate.html).

Substitution leads you to $\sigma R = \frac{\epsilon_0}{C}$.